# How to call image in folder PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, web

Web Developer.

I want to make my own wordpress plugin,
From what I look at add menu page parameters here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_menu_page/

```
add_menu_page( string $page_title, string $menu_title, string $capability, string $menu_slug, callable $function = '', string $icon_url = '', int $position = null )
```

you can insert icon url inside wordpress admin menu bars.

And, I look at Sassy Social Share Plugin, the code look like this:

```
$page = add_menu_page( __( 'Sassy Social Share by Heateor', 'sassy-social-share' ), 'Sassy Social Share', 'manage_options', 'heateor-sss-options', array( $this, 'options_page' ), plugins_url( '../images/logo.png', __FILE__ ) );
```

I did the same, but not working. The image not loaded.

I want to call icon.png in my image folder here:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tgh3b.png)

This is my code:

```
add_action("admin_menu", "addMenu");
function addMenu(){
    add_menu_page("Example Options", "Example Options", 4, "example-options", "insideMenu", '<img src="../image/icon.png/>"');
}

function insideMenu(){
    echo"<br/>";
    echo "Hello World";

}
```

Any help is appreciated, Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use:

```
add_menu_page('Sassy Social Share by Heateor', 'sassy-social-share', [...], plugins_url('/images/logo.png', __FILE__) );
```

The file path is relative to the .php file  (achan-plugin.php) and you should delete the "../" part. Also you should use **FILE** instead of FILE.

This works perfectly for me, with the same folder structure (/images/logo.png).

My full code:

```
// Add the moduleName Label in the Admin Menu with logo & config page
function moduleName_plugin_create_menu() 
{
  //create new top-level menu
  add_menu_page('moduleName Plugin Settings', 'moduleName', 'administrator', __FILE__, 'moduleName_plugin_settings_page' , plugins_url('/images/logo.png', __FILE__) );

}

//Add the Admin config page
function moduleName_plugin_settings_page() 
{
  include plugin_dir_path(__FILE__). '/views/admin/admin.php';
}
```